# How to remove data-toggle="modal" in specific window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner of the javascript. I want to remove the data-toggle attribute when the screen size is less than 760px and make the href working. I have no idea how to remove the data-toggle attribute, below is my code:

```
<div class="portfolio logo1 mix_all" data-cat="logo" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">                     
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" href="http://www.example.com/main/includes/onepager/business_service/example/index.php" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go thickbox">
            <img class="p-img" src="http://www.example.com/theme/mobile-page-files/web/images/small-portfolio/example.JPG" />
            <div class="b-wrapper">
                <h2 class="b-animate b-from-left b-delay03">
                    <img src="http://www.example.com/theme/mobile-page-files/web/images/link-ico.png" alt=""/>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="port-info">
        <h4>
            <a href="http://www.example.com/main/includes/onepager/business_service/example/index.php"> Example</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody addressed the case when the screen width might again be greater than 760. We'll have to add the data attribute back.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);

function resizeHandler() {
  var winWidth  = window.innerWidth,
      threshold = 760,
      els       = document.getElementsByClassName('thickbox');

  [].forEach.call(els, function (el) {   
    if (winWidth < threshold) {
      el.removeAttribute("data-toggle");
    } else {
      el.setAttribute("data-toggle", "bar");
    }  
  });
}
```

Check out this tiny demo to see it in action. http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/reZNNO

Comment: if i still have 7 more modal with the same coding as above (with different href), will this coding working for these 7 modals also?

Comment: I will adapt the demo for you so it works with multiple modals.

Comment: @TracyTan I updated my answer code as well as the Codepen demo so that it handles multiple modals. Done!

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your page (just before the `</body>` tag) add the following code :

```
if(window.innerWidth < 760){
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].removeAttribute("data-toggle");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of jQuery... Don't forget to update the selector `ELEMENTID`

```
if($(window).width() < 760){
     $('#ELEMENTID').find('a').removeAttr('data-toggle');
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, my modal-dialog still will pop-up when i try resize the window size less than 760px...